# form loading the last state it was before hide()

Tags: vba, vb6

I have 2 forms. I want to open the second form in the last state it was left? I mean changes intact, textfields changed, choices made etc etc. I try using .show but it does load the form from its load sub which resets the form from the fresh state.

Can anyone guide me here? Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to store the state of each control and set them back to what they were. Store the info somewhere on exit of the form and restore it on form_load or form_activate.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the form to reload, don't destroy it.

In the main form, store a reference to the single instance of the second form.

```
Private m_Dialog As Form2

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  If m_Dialog Is Nothing Then Set m_Dialog = New Form2

  m_Dialog.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  If Not m_Dialog Is Nothing Then Unload m_Dialog
  Set m_Dialog = Nothing
End Sub
```

In the second form, use `Hide()` to close it.

```
Private Sub OKButton_Click()
  Me.Hide
End Sub
```